# Akka ActorSelection over a whole cluser

Tags: java, akka, akka-cluster

I have a simple cluster with a service actor named "service" on each node. This service is respectively exposed with `ClusterClientRecptionist` to be able to use ist from outside the cluster with `ClusterClient`.

A client then registers users, which are created on random nodes of the cluster (because the `ClusterClient` dispatches randomly). For example `/user/service/user1` on node1 and `/user/service/user2` on node2.

What I want to do now, is to send a message to all registered users, independently of their physical location. I thout that was easy by using an `ActorSelection` like `/user/service/*`. But this only resolves local acotrs on the corresponding node.

I work with Java by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**

I just solved it by using the `DistributedPubSubMediator` as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30772983/how-to-broadcast-message-to-all-actors-in-an-akka-cluster-in-java) and documented [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/java/distributed-pub-sub.html).

```
private ActorRef mediator = DistributedPubSub.get(getContext().system()).mediator();

@Override
public void onReceive(Object msg) throws Exception {
    String msgStr = msg.toString();
    String val = msgStr.substring(4);
    if (msgStr.startsWith("add")) {
        ActorRef act = context().actorOf(Props.create(User.class, val), val);
        // subscribe the newly created user on topic "allUsers"
        mediator.tell(new DistributedPubSubMediator.Subscribe("allUsers", act), self());
        System.out.println("user created: " + act);
    } else if (msgStr.startsWith("say")) {
        // broadcast text message to all subscribed users
        mediator.tell(new DistributedPubSubMediator.Publish("allUsers", new Text(val)), self());
    }
}
```

**Option 2**

A second successful option is by using a BroadcastGroup router. Important is that the clustering is enabled in configuration:

```
akka.actor.deployment {
  /allUsers {
    router = broadcast-group
    routees.paths = ["/user/service/*"]
    cluster {
      enabled = on
      allow-local-routees = on
    }
  }
}
```

Afterwards, it can be used straightforward as documented.

```
ActorRef allUsers = system.actorOf(FromConfig.getInstance().props(), "allUsers");
[...]
allUsers.tell(new Text(val), self());
```